# sum of falling factorial $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{(k+1)!}a^{n-k-1} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I want to compute $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{(k+1)!}a^{n-k-1}$. I note that it is similar to a generating function. The coefficients are falling factorials. Can I simplify it? Thanks!

Comment: No formula (only maybe another type of a sum). Otherwise it would be possible to have a formula for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{(k+1)!}a^{n-k-1}=n!a^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(a^{-1}\right)^k}{k!}=a^n\left(\mathrm e^{a^{-1}}\Gamma\left(n+1,a^{-1}\right)-n!\right)\;,
\end{align}

where $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function. As user90369 noted in a comment, a "more closed" form than this doesn't exist, as it would lead to a closed form for the partial sums of the exponential series.